# How to remove my sub domain URL's from Google Indexing / Google Search Engine?

Tags: indexing, search-engine, duplicates, google-search-console

I have a blog website with both main domain and sub domain, like

- (i). maindomain.com
- (ii). staging.maindomain.com

Now Google is indexing both websites, i want to remove all sub domain URL's from Google search engine, Because sub domain is my staging server. I don't want to populate or get traffic in that. Can any one please suggest me in this, that could be really helpful for me.

- (i). How to remove all the sub domain URL's
- (ii). How to block the sub domain URL's from indexing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a robots.txt file and specify in that file which of the URLs you don't want Google to index.

To learn about robots.txt file, see [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, But the problem is : I have got indexed 85,000 sub-domain URL's, How could i define all the URL's in robots.txt